# Open Menu on click of Icon in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I am not able to identify how to display **Menu** items when clicked on **Icon** in **React Native**

[Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/@sharathm/menu)

**Code**

```
_onPressItem = () => {
    this.setState({ opened: true });
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListItem
          title={
            <View>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Mason Laon Roah</Text>
              <Text>9886012345</Text>
            </View>
          }
          subtitle={
            <View>
              <Text>445 Mount Eden Road, Mount Eden, Auckland. </Text>
              <Text>Contact No: 134695584</Text>
            </View>
          }
          leftAvatar={{ title: 'MD' }}
          rightContentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}
          rightTitle={<Icon type="material" color="red" name="more-vert" />}
        />
      </View>     
    );
  }

  getMenuView() {
    const { opened } = this.state;

    return (
      <MenuProvider style={{flexDirection: 'column', padding: 30}}>
        <Menu
          opened={opened}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.onBackdropPress()}
          onSelect={value => this.onOptionSelect(value)}>
          <MenuTrigger onPress={() => this._onPressItem()} text="Menu Icon Here" />
          <MenuOptions>
            <MenuOption value={1} text='One' />
            <MenuOption value={2}>
              <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Two</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption value={3} disabled={true} text='Three' />
          </MenuOptions>
        </Menu>
      </MenuProvider>
    );
  }
```

Please let me know how to integrate Menu with Icon..

Basically all the items are displayed in **FlatList** where each item have its **own** Menu Item

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Update Code below:

instead of:

```
rightTitle={<Icon type="material" color="red" name="more-vert" />}
```

update to:

```
rightTitle={this.getMenuView()}
```

Because this Method returns view not Menu popup.

and instead of:

```
<MenuTrigger onPress={() => this._onPressItem()} text="Menu Icon Here" />
```

update to:

```
<MenuTrigger onPress={() => this._onPressItem()}>
              <Icon type="material" color="red" name="more-vert" />
          </MenuTrigger>
```

so that instead of printing text, it shows icon.

I tried this code on your given link, it works..

Comment: hi its working but can you check out the expo link which i have shared the menu seems to be going out of screen

Comment: I checked the expo link, I can't find the problem you are referring to. everything seems fine. Can u share snapshot of the problem?